# How to send and read String over serial between two Arduinos?

Tags: string, arduino, send

Good morning/afternoon/evening. I'm trying to build this project and I have two arduinos (Emitter & Receiver) and they're gonna comunicate using RF control. The emitter/controller reads 2 different analog inputs with potentiometers connected, creates an String called "parametro" with the values of both potentiometers (Ex: "05120512" - 50%/50% - "10231023" - 100%/100%) and send this String via serial to the receiver using Serial.print(parametro). It works just fine.

The problem is: how to read that String as a String on the other Arduino. I've tried to read each byte of the String and create a char array with the values, and then, convert it back to String. However, there are some bug I can't explain. I tried to change the delay() time and it worked at first, but then, the numbers got random or something. I left the potenciometers on the middle position, so when I use Serial.print(parametro) to send data from the controller straight to the serial monitor it works as expected: "05120512051205120512...."

But when I try to send it from the receiver using Serial.println(parametro), it gives me something like:

- 05120512
- 05120512
- 05120512
- 05120512
- **05120052**
- **05205105**
- **10510510**
- **51051051**

As you can see, at that point the numbers start to get messed up and I don't understand why. Can anyone show me another solution or tell me what I did wrong?

By the way, here are the codes of the receiver. The emitter works fine, as I said:

```js
  //      READING FUNCTION
String lerString(){
String conteudo = "";
char caracteres[8];
// WHILE RECEIVING
for(int i=0;i<=7;i++){
  caracteres[i] = Serial.read();
  delay(10);
  conteudo.concat(caracteres[i]);
}
return conteudo;
}


void loop() {

  //      SERIAL READ
  if(Serial.available() > 0){
    parametro = lerString(); 
  }
  Serial.println(parametro);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would get a more robust implementation if you use a delimiter and implement a simple state machine to walk you through the parsing (ie. string -> "#05120512" that way your receiving function could look like:

```
void loop () {
   if (Serial.available) {
      byte = Serial.read();
      if (byte == '#') {
          // got delimiter: start receiving data
          leState = RECEIVING_DATA
          count = 0;
      } else if (leState == RECEVING_DATA){
          count++;
          data[count] = byte;
          if (count == 7) {
              // print data
              ...
              // reset state machine
              leState = WAITING_FOR_DELIMITER;
          }
      }
   }

}
```

Warning: untested code - proceed with caution

Comment: Thank you, ananio. I had to do some little changes, but it worked out as expected. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

From the information given, I'm assuming your problem has to do with you reading the serial port every time something is available (not necessarily the whole 8 bytes/chars you want).

Your check `Serial.available() > 0` is true whenever any single character is on the serial port. Meaning that you call your `lerString()` function prematurely.

Adjust the check to be greater than the size of the message you hope to receive (e.g. 8 bytes).

```
void loop() {

  //      SERIAL READ
  //   Change from 0 to 8 VVV
  if(Serial.available() >= 8){
  parametro = lerString(); 
  Serial.println(parametro);
  }
}
```